# Tikz & Geometry package (elimination of space)

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, geometry, book-design, bleed

I use **geometry package** for preparing a book with **bleeds**. This book would contain a simple graphics done by **tikz**.

Firstly, a space above my tikz picture has been observed (in overlay mode), although the position is set to `(0mm,0mm)`. Of couse, I know about a space above tikz picture in this mode, **but how to eliminate it**?

Secondly, I want to use specific commands, like `\textwidth` etc., so I am looking for a simple solution. Existing replies on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) have not worked in my case.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=40mm, opacity=0.2, minimum width=\textwidth, anchor=north  west] at (0mm,0mm) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the `\topskip`: The base of the first line is always a bit below the top of the text body. You need to move your picture up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=40mm, opacity=0.2, minimum width=\textwidth, anchor=north  west] at (0mm,\topskip) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]